# In Talend how to fetch latest file

Tags: talend

I have three files which are having the same schema,

```
A1(file) received at 12:30:000.00,
A2(file) received at 12:35:000.00,
A3(file) received at 12:40:000.00.
```

Now I want to fetch the latest file which is A3.

Note: I have used to tfilelist component to fetch the file.

Answer (score 2):

[Talend Docs for tFileList](https://help.talend.com/reader/MjIZDoU6r0vLbCpGh5GAcg/8n6CoqqqbFSdHMxL6goOyw):

> Order by:
>
> **By modified date**: most recent to least recent or least recent to most recent.

The Talend Knowledge Base has a load of information about components. Also, the components speak mostly for themselves if you examine them a bit.

Comment: Hi Tobi, 
Assume that in an existing table, A1 and A2 file records are there, now I want to load only A3 file records.

Comment: Hey, you could use something like tAggregateRow.

Answer (score 1):

tFileList --> tFileProperties --> tJavaRow

- tFileList to iterate over the file list
- tFileProperties to get files properties
- tJavaRow to save the filepath (using a global variable) for the file with the greatest value for mtime field

After that, tFileInputDelimited using the global variable for filename

Comment: You may order the file list to get the most recent 1st, then in tJavaRow, set the global variable only if it is null to get the 1st filepath only.

Does this help or not.
A feedback would be appreciate.

Comment: As you said in above scenario, I have been trying to implement, but I couldn't able to get the results.
1.In tFileList I've selected the path. 
2.I have Iterate to the tfile properties.
3.From tfile properties(In this component do I need to give the file name) to tJavaRow, In this component what should, I need to give???
4.tfileinputdelimeter, I have given a current file path, and an input file delimiter it won't accept the main link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job with these components:

tFileList -> tFileProperties -> tAggregateRow -> tLogRow (or any output component)

In `tFileList` provide the Directory Path.

`tFileProperties` contains schema corresponding to the properties of the file like basename, Modified time, Absolute Path etc.

In `tFileProperties` pass the global variable for the filepath ie `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))`.

In `tAggregaterow` under Operations section select the columns to be displayed & use Max function for `mtime_string` column.

Answer (score 0):

Talend - Fetch latest file from each directory

Please check the YouTube for reference and below are the high-level steps.

https://youtu.be/_3UQfjtaYlg

1. Get the list of directories using tFilelist.
2. For each directory - List all the files using tFilelist
3. Assign numbers of each file in the folder - Using sequence number
4. Fetch the latest file with seq no 1 and write the file path to new file using tFileoutputdelimited
5. Read the file name which has the file path for processing and process each file using tFileinputdelimited

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).